# Required error msg before custom error msg

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have some class using Data Annotations in asp.net mvc.

The problem is that when the user types nothing into the field, my custom validation fires and gives a msg that the data is incorrect.

The thing is, I'd like to display to the user the error that is linked with empty field - required error Msg.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(pl.accountNumberRequiredErrorMsg), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(pl))]
    [Display(Name = nameof(pl.accountNumber), ResourceType = typeof(pl))]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(pl.accountNumberFieldTooLongErrorMsg), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(pl))]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Namespace.Validators.AccountNumber(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(pl.accountNumberNotValidErrorMsg), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(pl))]
    public string accountNumber{ get; set; }
```

all displayed text is from resources.

User gets the 
**accountNumberNotValidErrorMsg** 
but should 
**accountNumberRequiredErrorMsg** 
because the user didn't write anything in the field.

Is there a way to make sure that the first error would be the required error?

Comment: Put all the logic into Namespace.Validators.AccountNumber, why do you need so many validators if at the end you are just going to create your own custom one?

Comment: Well, I would like to have two different messages. If user input is null then: Field is required. If user wrote something but incorrectly: The account number is incorrect. Is there a way to achieve this using only one validator?

Comment: Use stringlength insteaf of required then

Comment: Still the wrong error appears. It seems that the custom validator is kind of more imporant than others. I've written second custom validator only for checking if the input is null and it kind of works but it's not the cleanest way, for sure.

Comment: Make the stringlength from 1, and remove required

Comment: That's exactly what I've done